# For loop in App Script stopping at line 9

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day;

I am working on a spreadsheet that will highlight contracts that have expired. The thought was to create a for loop to go through the rows, check the end date of the contract (column 3) and compare it to the current date. Base on the value the cell will be set to green, red, or blue. In addition if the cells value is not a date the log should record that.

The question is everything appears to be working however; the script stops at line 9 every time. Currently there are 21 lines on the sheet. Column 3 (minus the header), all have dates formatted like mm/dd/yyyy. Does anyone have an idea why this stops at row nine?

Cells c10 and down are coming in as objects? Not sure if this is causing the issue.

````
function moveCompletedRows() {
  var dodSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Main Spreadsheet
  var firstSheet = dodSheet.getSheetByName("POP Template"); //Sheet where unevaluated lines are. 
  var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy"); //creating a date and formating mm/dd/yyy
  
  // let testCell = firstSheet.getRange(10,3).getValue();
  // Logger.log(typeof testCell);
  // Logger.log(typeof firstSheet.getRange(9,3).getValue());

  let i = 2;// i starting at two so it doesn't evaluate headers
  // Logger.log(i);

  for(i; i<=firstSheet.getLastRow(); i++){

    var firstRange = firstSheet.getRange(i,3,i,10).getValue();
    var cellDate = Utilities.formatDate(firstRange,"EST", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    
    //test if date is in the future
    if(cellDate[i] > todayDate){
        let testColor = firstSheet.getRange(i,3);
        testColor.setBackground("red");
        Logger.log(i + " great");
    }
    //test if date is current day
    else if(cellDate[i] == todayDate){
        let testColor = firstSheet.getRange(i,3);
        testColor.setBackground("blue");
        Logger.log(i + " equal");
    }
    //test if date is in the past
    else if(cellDate[i] < todayDate){
      let testColor = firstSheet.getRange(i,3);
      testColor.setBackground("green");
      Logger.log(i +" less");
    }
    //remaining items that aren't formated correctly. 
    else {
      Logger.log("Not a date");
    }
    // Logger.log(i);
  }

  // Logger.log(firstRange);
  // Logger.log(cellDate);
  // Logger.log(todayDate);
  // Logger.log(cellDate.valueOf());
  // Logger.log(todayDate.valueOf());
}```
````

Comment: This makes no sense: `var firstRange = sh1.getRange(i,3,i,10).getValue();`  you are setting both the row and the number of rows to i and you are using getValue() for a multicell range.  You obviously need to reread  the documentation for getValues() and getValue().

Answer (score 0):

**Comparing dates numerically and setting column D background color based on date value**

Your function does not move any rows but here is what I  believe you were trying to accomplish other than moving rows.

```
function settingColumnDBackgroundColor) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("POP Template"); 
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange(2, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dt = new Date()
  var dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  vs1.forEach((r, i) => {
    let dv = new Date(r[3]).valueOf();//date value of columnD
    if(dv > dtv) {
      sh1.getRange(i+2,3).setBackground("#ff0000")
    } else if(dv == dtv) {
      sh1.getRange(i + 2,3 ).setBackground("#0000ff");
    } else if(dv < dtv) {
      sh1.getRange(i + 2, 3).setBackground("#00ff00");
    }
  });
}
```

- [Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)
- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Yes, thank you. It’s funny how once you see it correctly I just think o yea duh.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeated `setBackgound()`, I would suggest you get the values, loop through them and use `setBackgounds()` as shown below.

```
function moveCompletedRows() {
  let dodSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Main Spreadsheet
  let firstSheet = dodSheet.getSheetByName("POP Template"); //Sheet where unevaluated lines are. 
  let todayDate = new Date();
  todayDate = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(),todayDate.getMonth(),todayDate.getDate()); // remove time
  todayDate = todayDate.valueOf();

  let range = firstSheet.getRange(2,3,firstSheet.getLastRow()-1,1);
  let values = range.getValues();
  console.log(values);

  let testColor = [];

  for( let i=0; i<values.length; i++){

    try {
      //test if date is in the future
      if( values[i][0].valueOf() > todayDate ){
        testColor.push(["red"]);
      }
      //test if date is current day
      else if( values[i][0].valueOf() === todayDate ){
        testColor.push(["blue"]);
      }
      //test if date is in the past
      else if( values[i][0].valueOf() < todayDate ){
        testColor.push(["green"]);
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
       testColor.push([null]);
    }
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(testColor);
}
```

Reference

- [Spreadsheet Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Nice, appreciate the response I do like this approach.

Comment: I realized if the value is not a date it will throw an error.   So would suggest your modify as shown above with a try {} catch() {} block.